# language change in visual recognition in swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, image-recognition

I am trying to change the language response in classify function in an iOS app using ibm visual recognition. I tried change it to to French but I still get the response in English, here is how I call the function:

```
visualRecognition.classify(imagesFile: fileURL,  acceptLanguage: "fr", success:{(classifiedImages) in.....
```

Comment: working now, don't know if ibm fixed it with the new version or my code fixed it:visualRecognition.classify(imagesFile: fileURL, acceptLanguage: lcode, success:{(classifiedImages)